# Дружественная функция при перекрестных ссылках

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Проблема в следующем. Есть два класса - diarySportsmen (основной класс) и ExceptionHandler (вспомогательный класс, обработчик исключений). Один из методов класса ExceptionHandler необходимо подружить с diarySportsmen для доступа к некоторым приватным полям. Но вот загвоздка - перекрестные ссылки, в хедере diarySportsmen подключен ExceptionHandler и наоборот. Как подружить функцию в этом случае?
Код прилагаю ниже

Хедер класса diarySportsmen

```
    #ifndef DIARYSPORTSMEN_H
#define DIARYSPORTSMEN_H

#include "diary.h"
#include "exceptionhandler.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSignalMapper>


class diarySportsmen : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit diarySportsmen(QWidget *parent = 0);
    diarySportsmen(QString);
    ~diarySportsmen();
    friend void ExceptionHandler::exceptionIncorrectTimeData(diarySportsmen*, int);

private:

    int code;
    QComboBox *cbStyle;
    QPushButton *confirmStyle;
    QLabel **arrDist;
    std::vector <QLabel*> arrPrevTime;
    std::vector <QLabel*> arrCurrTime;
    QLineEdit **arrEnterTime;
    std::vector<QPushButton*> arrConfirmsTime;
    QPushButton *b25;
    QPushButton *b50;
    QPushButton *detailedStatistic;
    QLabel *welcome;

    QSignalMapper *smNewTime;

    QString sportName;
    QString chooseStyle;
    int pool;

    void CreateWidgets();
    void CreateDiaryWidgets();
    void SetTime(QString, int);
    void SetStyle(QLabel*, QString, QString, QString);

    static QString deleteSpace(QString);

private slots:
    void actionConfirmStyle();
    void actionCbStyle();
    void actionAddTime(int);
    void action25meters();
    void action50meters();
    void actionShowDetailedStatistic();

};
```

Хедер класса ExceptionHandler

```
    #ifndef EXCEPTIONHANDLER_H
#define EXCEPTIONHANDLER_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "diarysportsmen.h"

class ExceptionHandler
{

public:
    ExceptionHandler();
    ~ExceptionHandler();

    static void exceptionNoTimeData(QMainWindow*); //на данной дистанции нет ни одного сохраненного времени
    static void exceptionOverflowTimeData(QMainWindow*); //для данной дистанции невозможно добавить новое время (переполнение)
    static void exceptionIncorrectTimeData(class diarySportsmen*, int); //неверный формат времени
    static void exceptionIncorrectTimeRange(QMainWindow*); //указан неверный отрезок времени для статистики (<0 или >365)
    static void exceptionIncorrectDistanceData(QMainWindow*); //указана неверная дистанция для отображения нормативов
    static void exceptionInsufficientDistanceData(QMainWindow*); //недостаточно данных для отображения нормативов (неактивна одна или более из 5 групп радиокнопок)
    static void exceptionEmptyEnter(QWidget*); //невозможно добавить нового спортсмена (отсутствует фамилия или имя)
    static void exceptionNullList(QWidget*); //невозможно обновить список - список пуст
    static void exceptionNullStyle(QWidget*); //не выбран стиль плавания

    static void exceptionNoDetected(QMainWindow*);//общее неизвестное исключение
    static void exceptionNoDetected(QWidget*);//общее неизвестное исключение

private:
};
```

Да, это только малая часть всего проекта, поэтому так много "лишних" методов в обработчике

Comment: Не берусь судить о правильности дизайна. Поэтому только ответ на вопрос: используйте предварительное объявление, его достаточно для определения friend.

Comment: Вообще-то наоборот, для объявления класса `ExceptionHandler` достаточно предварительного объявления `diarySportsmen`.

Comment: @VTT точно, я предварительно объявлял ExceptionHandler, шарики за ролики немного заехали уже) спасибо, все работает